# Is the prime graph of a metacyclic group connected?

Tags: finite-groups

For a finite group $G$, let $\pi(G)$ be the set of prime divisors of $|G|$. Define a graph $GK(G)$ with vertex set $\pi(G)$ and an edge between $p$ and $q$ if and only if $G$ contains an element of order $pq$.

My question is whether $GK(G)$ is connected, if $G$ is a metacyclic group.

Comment: Perhaps you should define the prime graph.

Answer (score 1):

$S_3$ is metacyclic and has disconnected prime graph: two nodes, one for $2$ and one for $3$, with no edge between them (there is no element of order $6$). This is not research level.